# Printing dictionary in a While Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been looking around to see if anyone has actually done it but couldn't find it so hoping I can get some help here.

```
newDict = {'Jan':31, 'Feb':29, 'Mar':31, 'Apr':30, 'May':31, 'Jun':30, 'Jul':31, 'Aug':30}
```

I created this dict and I want to use a `while` loop to output it this way:

```
Jan 31
Feb 29
Mar 31
Apr 30
May 31
Jun 30
Jul 31
Aug 30
```

I am able to do it with a `for` loop, just curious how it can be done with a `while` loop.

Comment: I am very curious: Why do you want use a while loop?

Comment: @Moberg Hi, I wanted to try different ways to see how I am able to print dictionary instead of using For loop which is easier to use.

Comment: You should seriously consider learning Python 3, Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life in 2020.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your dictionary an `iterator` calling `iteritems` (Python 2.x), or `iter` on the `items()` (Python 3.x)

```
# Python 2.x
from __future__ import print_function
items = newDict.iteritems()

# Python 3.x
items = iter(newDict.items())

while True:
    try: 
        item = next(items)
        print(*item)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

*Note: We're importing `print_function` on Python 2.x because `print` would be a statement instead of a function, and hence the line `print(*item)` would actually fail*

Comment: this throws an Error on me `'dict_itemiterator' object has no attribute 'next'`. Did you try it?

Comment: There's `dict.iteritems()`, which is already an iterator. But you should use the `next` function rather than calling the `.next` method directly. FWIW, in Python 3, `.next` doesn't exist, it's now `.__next__`, making it consistent with the other special methods.

Comment: I haven't tried it on Python 3.x, but it's working on Python 2.x

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It [does actually](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Comment: `print(*item)` wont work in Python 2, so have to use `print item[0], item[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option, using the `.pop` method.

```
newDict = {
    'Jan':31, 'Feb':29, 'Mar':31, 'Apr':30, 
    'May':31, 'Jun':30, 'Jul':31, 'Aug':30
}
t = newDict.items()
while t:
    print '%s %d' % t.pop()
```

**typical output**

```
Jul 31
Jun 30
Apr 30
Aug 30
Feb 29
Mar 31
May 31
Jan 31
```

This code doesn't modify the contents of `newDict`, since in Python 2 `dict.items()` creates a list of the (key, value) pairs of the dictionary. In Python 3 it returns a dynamic View object, which doesn't have a `.pop` method, so this code won't work there.

Bear in mind that a `dict` is an unordered collection, so the output order may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This is an absurd requirement, but here is one way to do it:

```
newDict = {'Jan':31, 'Feb':29, 'Mar':31, 'Apr':30, 'May':31, 'Jun':30, 'Jul':31, 'Aug':30}

while newDict:
  x = next(x for x in newDict)
  print(x, newDict.pop(x))
```

---

**CAUTION:**

After the `while` has finished executing, `newDIct` will be **empty**.

Comment: This is the most efficient method out of all presented. To make it even better I would drop `next()` and just use a regular `for x in newDict` and after processing `newDict.pop(x)` just use `break`.

Comment: The reason this is not absurd is because there are cases where a dictionary is taking up a lot of memory and all you need to do is process a record and get rid of it, so you are freeing up memory as you process data

Comment: @hndcrftd A `for` loop in which the object you iterate changes is not optimal. you could though get the `len`gth of the `dict` and iterate on that. This way you do not need `break`

Comment: @ev-kounis well, no I couldn't. The  whole point of using a single iteration of `for` is to get a key, as dictionaries are not indexed and the goal is not to create any lists. the `break` basically makes the `next()` unnecessary,  but otherwise I'm doing what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
key=list(newDict.keys())
i=0
while i<len(key):
    print(key[i]," ",newDict[key[i]])
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `while` loop.

```
newDict = {'Jan':31, 'Feb':29, 'Mar':31, 'Apr':30, 'May':31, 'Jun':30, 'Jul':31, 'Aug':30}
i = 0
while i < len(newDict):
    val = newDict.items()[i]
    print val[0], val[1]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators)

**Python 2.7**

```
new_dict = {'Jan':31, 'Feb':29, 'Mar':31, 'Apr':30, 'May':31, 'Jun':30, 'Jul':31, 'Aug':30}
a = iter(new_dict.iteritems())
default = object()

while a:
    elem = next(a, default)
    # This check is to know whether iterator is exhausted or not.
    if elem is default:
        break
    print "{} {}".format(*elem)
```

**Python 3**

```
new_dict = {'Jan':31, 'Feb':29, 'Mar':31, 'Apr':30, 'May':31, 'Jun':30, 'Jul':31, 'Aug':30}
a = iter(new_dict.items())
default = object()

while a:
    elem = next(a, default)
    # This check is to know whether iterator is exhausted or not.
    if elem is default:
        break
    print("{} {}".format(*elem))
```